# Using unknown range of cells in vba formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to calculate the number of cases that are running at the time any given case during the day starts. I have a basic formula for getting this number but I have to calculate it for multiple doctors per day for an entire year.

I am trying to automate writing this equation

`"COUNTIFS($G$14:$G$21,"<="&G20, $H$14:$H$21,">="&G20)` 
where `G20` is the start time of the case, the `"G"` range is the start time of all the cases that day and the `"H"` range is the end time of all cases that day.

The problem is that the `"G" and "H" ranges` change depending on the number of cases a doctor performed on a given day.

Using `VBA` is there a way to tell the macro to calculate the necessary range of cells in the middle of the equation?**

I tried using the .`Offset property` inside the equation to navigate to the necessary cells, but that obviously didn't work. I also tried specifying the needed ranges as an object and referring to the object in the middle of the equation but since it's not a variable that didn't work either.

Below is an example of the code I'm working with and the location of where I'd need the varying ranges.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(" & (Insert "G" Range of Cells Here) & ",""<=""&RC[-24]," & (Insert "H" Range of Cells Here) & ","">=""&RC[-24])"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

Thank you in advance for any advice or tips you can provide.

Update 2/8/2019:

The ranges I need are separated by a blank row, that's how I know how many rows I need in each range.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: How do you determine the beginning and end in the columns? eg `$G$14:$G$21` how do you caclulate 14 and 21 here? Maybe a screenshot helps to explain it.

Comment: I added a screen shot in reference to the above comment.

Comment: Use a [last row calculation](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) and store in a variable then concatenate that variable into your string. Essentially, it will give the end row for your range address.

Comment: Since you are using `COUNTIFS`, why not add a condition for the Dr.'s name? `"COUNTIFS(G:G,"<="&G20, H:H,">="&G20, E:E, E20)`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I did not think of that, thank you! I also had to add a condition for the date since the same Dr. will have multiple work days in the data set but that seems to have worked.

Comment: @QHarr I think your suggestion would have eventually led to a working solution as well.  Thank you all!